# How to update Xml file recuperated from a web service?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm developping a phonegap/android application. I have recuperated an xml file from a web service using xmlhttprequest, now I want to insert, delete or modify some tags.
How can I do this and should I use Get or post.

Comment: What language are you wanting to modify the xml file with?  Javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1192286/403404

Comment: The link I provided should get you started then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add data you should use POST.
I don't think you can modify the XML file recuperated directly, because it shows informations from the database, so you can access to the data base, then put or modify what you want, then the XML file will be modified.