# How can i write to xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

i am struck in problem of writing to an XML file. I know how to read an xml file. Let me explain it clearly. I have to read the value from an xml file and pass it to a label or listbox and then write the value to another xml file. I did the first part of reading and i am struck in writing. I have gone through several queries in stackoverflow. But its not working for me. Help me out
Here is the code which i used for writing

```
var v = new  XMLWriter();
   v.writeStartDocument(true);
   v.writeElementString('option','Hello World');
   v.writeAttributeString('foo','bar');
   v.writeEndDocument();
   console.log( v.flush() );
```

Comment: In a browser? Node? Something else?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. if i give some text to a text box it has to be saved to a xml file in the same directory

Comment: I think your environment would become a lot clearer if you posted your code reading the xml file.

Comment: So... in a browser? Node? Something else?

Comment: @praveen singh, you are clueless. In the browser you cannot save local files. Imagine if this would be possible then every website can fill your computer up with garbage and worse things. If you are working with a server-side solution, please indicate so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192286/create-and-modify-xml-file-using-javascript)

```
function test(){    
 var v = new  XMLWriter();
 v.writeStartDocument(true);
 v.writeElementString('test','Hello World');
 v.writeAttributeString('foo','bar');
 v.writeEndDocument();
 console.log( v.flush() );
}
```

that will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="true" ?>
 <test foo="bar">Hello World</test>
```

Comment: My doubt is where the xml file will be saved

Comment: @praveensingh dear it will not generate a file. It will generate xml in your browser. You can use that then to do any thing