# Writing jquery object to XML

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, xml

i am trying to write my object to an xml file. but i get error in my Writexml function.

```
     function writexml(listXML) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "c:\\users\nagia\documents\visual studio2013\Projects\Webtrystuff\Webtrystuff\XMLFile1.xml",   //path 
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: { filename: "XMLFile1.xml", content: listXML },
            error: function () {
                alert("Unknown error. Data could not be written to the file.");
            },
            success: function () {
                window.open("XMLFile1.xml");
            }
        });
      }
```

This is my function to call the writexml.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function(date)  {
                        var event = events[date];
                        writexml(event);

                        if (event) {
                       return [true, event.className, event.text, event.date];
                        }
                        else {
                            return [true, '', ''];
                        }

                    }
                })
            });
            </script>
```

event is a my object in jquery.

```
    var Event = function (text, className) {
        this.text = text;
        this.className = className;

       };
```

I have to use ajax. Is there something wrong with sending the object like this? I am a beginner.

Comment: I also tried giving the path of my xml file like "~/XMLFile1.xml" ...still got the error case.

Comment: are you... trying to do a POST to an xml file?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12000090/526704

Comment: yes post to a local xml file ...

Comment: that's not going to work. an XML file is not a web server.

Comment: well what can I do then ? my assingmnent question says that "function will make an Ajax call and save those events in a XML file" how can I save my "even"t object using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this code in a browser? 
In that case I'm not sure but i think that you could have a problem of cross domain call.
In your code the url definition is incorrect because is the link of a resources in your filesystem with a absolute path:

```
url: "c:\\users\nagia\documents\visual studio2013\Projects\Webtrystuff\Webtrystuff\XMLFile1.xml"
```

From your browser, for security reason you cannot call resources outside of your domain.

[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-domain_solution) for the wiki page about Crossdomain call

you can se more about this problem in this stackoverflow thread [Using AJAX to read local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files)

Comment: I am writing to a local xml file. I am running the code in a webform.

Comment: Then it should work with the relative url "~/XMLFile1.xml" but why isnt then?

Comment: for cross domain problems I already have CORS extension installed in my browser so that cant be an issue