# how to read & write external xml file in apache cordova?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, apache-cordova

I am creating android app. I want to use xml file just to store a little amount of data for short period of time..
I am able to read xml using ajax.get() method file but not able to write xml..
Please help me to do so..

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Could be great

Comment: can you suggest me which ajax method should i use to update xml file

Comment: Please read my above answer

Comment: i am not interested in reading whole bunch of instructions.. 

just a short help

Comment: If you aren't interested in research or reading...why should we be interested in helping?

Comment: I totally agree with you.. But i am running out of time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a little amount of data and you are using cordova, you could use get and set local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

and

```
var agentSmith=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

as w3school says:

> With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the
>   user's browser.

but if you want to use xml, you could do:

```
var v = new  XMLWriter();
   v.writeStartDocument(true);
   v.writeElementString('test','Hello ');
   v.writeAttributeString('foo','bar');
   v.writeEndDocument();
   console.log( v.flush() );
```

and obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="true" ?>
<test foo="bar">Hello World</test>
```

like here [create and modify xml file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192286/create-and-modify-xml-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanx for the answer bro.. I really appreciate..

But I am looking for the xml way only..

Comment: Thanx a lot bro..

Perfect answer